# Days countdown iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, nstimer, countdown

My app requires that I start countdown of days from first launch. If someone launch my app for the first time I want to count day 1 after 12 midnight (using the device clock of course) and then day2 ... and perform an action after the 21st day. It shouldn't matter if the person close the app or switch off phone. When the app come back up, it should automatically detect how many days have passed.

Does anyone have an idea how to realise that ? . I am thinking of NStimer  but kind of confuse.

Comment: if you use device clock, the user will be able to change it or it may be set wrong.

Comment: Actually it doesn't matter if the User change device time or set it incorrectly. I just want to be able to count days that have passed.

Comment: I am try something in playground ... no real solution yet .... I thought of setting NStimer with interval to call a function that get the device date every 12 hours (or every time the app relaunch) then find if its different from the previous cache date ... if yes count +1

Answer (score 3):

I think you want to use `UILocalNotification`. That would allow you to alert the user regardless if your app is active or not.

Please consult the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/), do a trial implementation and ask a new stack overflow question if you get stuck and cannot find an answer.

Comment: I am try something in playground ... no real solution yet .... I thought of setting NStimer with interval to call a function that get the device date every 12 hours (or every time the app relaunch) then find if its different from the previous cache date ... if yes count +1

Answer (score 0):

Ok, After fiddling around for some time and tried several stuffs in playground, I came up with a solution that work just perfect. So in case someone is trying to work out something similar, here is my solution.

```
    func checkElapsedDay (){

    //make sure the date register only run 1 time.
    if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("firstLaunch"){

        lauchDate =  NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("start")! as! NSDate
        endDate = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("end")! as! NSDate
    }
    else{

        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "firstLaunch")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

        endDate = lauchDate.dateByAddingTimeInterval(1814400) // 1814400 = 21 days
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(lauchDate, forKey: "start")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(endDate, forKey: "end")
    }

    var today = NSDate()
    let compareResult = today.compare(endDate)
    let cal = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let unit:NSCalendarUnit = .CalendarUnitDay
    let components = cal.components(unit, fromDate: today, toDate: endDate, options: nil)
    let biss = cal.compareDate(today, toDate: endDate, toUnitGranularity: nil)
    var bbb = components.day
    daysleft.image = UIImage(named: "\(bbb).png") //change the remaining day stamp

}
```